# dynamic url rewrite using htacess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

i want to display the this url

```
http://localhost/project/sites/sample/cat.php?typ=Politics
```

to like this

```
http://localhost/project/sites/sample/Politics.html
```

and my htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ cat.php?typ=$1
```

it's working when i was gave the url manually on browser, but the url was not loaded dynamically. i want to show the  second url dynamical if i click the first url.
thank you to help

Answer (score 1):

Try this Rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*).html$ cat.php?typ=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `RewriteRule` to `Redirect`:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect (.*)\.html$ cat.php?typ=$1
```

<sub>*By the way, "typ" is written as "type"</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect form the first URL to the second:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^typ=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^cat\.php$ cat/%1/? [R,L]
```

If you want to edit the links in your HTML you could try `mod_substitute` (make sure that `mod_filter` is also enabled):

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute s|/?cat\.php\?typ=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|/cat/$1/|i
```

Answer (score 1):

if you type manually your new link it works right?

simply have your html link point to "Politics.html" instead of "cat.php?typ=Politics"
htaccess will take care of the rest